# Overriding parent CSS attribute

Tags: css, inheritance

I have this CSS:

```
a:hover {
  background-color:#D1E1EA;
  color:#19558D;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

for all links in my app. However, on one specific link I want to nullify all of this `hover` behavior. How can I do this?

Note that it's not as simple as redefining these attributes for the specific link, because the color of the specific link changes, and so I couldn't just choose one `background-color`...

Comment: I don't understand the title of your question.

Comment: @BoltClock - I don't even understand the body of the question. I thought he couldn't set a specific background color...

Comment: He's saying that there is a parent CSS file that modifies the anchor tag's hover selector with the 3 lines in the body (as shown), and he'd like that to not happen in an inheriting css file; specifically he wants the specified behavior shown to just not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by overwrite, but you can try setting the background color to transparent, so you're not specifying a specific colour.

```
a:hover.moreSpecific{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I previously posted a comment saying you couldn't do this, but there's a `:not()` selector in CSS 3 that could do this. [It just won't work in IE < 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37). I think you'd have to use JS to do it in IE.

```
a:hover:not(#specific_link) {
  background-color:#D1E1EA;
  color:#19558D;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) CSS properties allow you to `inherit` from the parent element:

```
a:hover.special {
    background: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can't use `inherit` on anything except `direction` and `visibility` in IE < 8. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue

Comment: Fair point. Your CSS3 method is cleaner anyway (and can be made to work in IE6-8 with something like selectivizr.js).